# how to check validation faild or not inside $validator->after(function ($validator) { }); laravel

Tags: php, laravel

part of my controller

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'displayed_total_rate' => 'required', 
  'is_dropoff_city_defferent' => 'nullable|in:1,0',
  //some other fields ...
]);
    
    
$validator->after(function ($validator) use ($request) {
   if (!$validator->fails()) {
    if ($some_checkings_if_prevous_validation_not_failed) {
        $validator->errors()->add('field', 'some error');
    }
   }
});
```

at the execution of code

```
if (!$validator->fails()) {
```

it run infinitly, so how to check the prevous validation failed or not inside $validator->after function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but is there a specific reason why you want to do the fail check and the the error adding in `$validator->after`?

From what i can see, the easiest way would be this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'displayed_total_rate' => 'required', 
  'is_dropoff_city_defferent' => 'nullable|in:1,0',
  //some other fields ...
]);

if (!$validator->fails()) {
    if ($some_checkings_if_prevous_validation_not_failed) {
        $validator->errors()->add('field', 'some error');
    }
}
```